# Error : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, fetch, nutch

I am new in nutch and solr integration.

I want to crawl new urls so I installed both solr version 4.6.0 and nutch version 1.6 in ubuntu.First I start with some configuration but i still get this error:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: File:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/crawl_fetch
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin   /20150529030452/crawl_parse
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_data
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_text

In the file logs I get this error:

> 2015-05-29 03:05:41,153 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation -PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera
>
> cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/crawl_fetch
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/crawl_parse
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_data
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_text
>
> 2015-05-29 03:05:41,153 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/crawl_fetch
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/crawl_parse
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_data
>
> Input path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/20150529030452/parse_text

Whats the meaning of this, can you please explain whats the issue and how can I solve it.

I will highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `bin/crawl` from Mac OS or any Unix-based operating system like FreeBSD, then switch to Ubuntu. I believe this is a bug the crawl script has. I faced this before and used Ubuntu instead.